# Extending linear operators to multi-linear ones

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we are given a linear operator $L$ on a Banach space $X$.  Is there any way to extend $L$ to a multi-linear operator $\mathcal{L}$ in such a way that
$$\mathcal{L}(x_1, x_2^*, \ldots, x_n^*) = L(x_1)$$
for some fixed values of $x^*_2, \ldots, x_n^*$?

If this seems too difficult, any insight on how to canonically associate $L$ to a multi-linear operator would also be interesting.

Comment: What are you suggesting for the new domain of this multilinear operator? $X^{\otimes n}$? (I presume it's an endomorphism) You need to provide more information as to what you want.

Comment: Kate's first suggestion, making $\mathcal L$ depend only on its first argument, isn't multi-linear.  The simplest solution, quite close to Kate's second suggestion, is to use `$L(x_1)f(x_2)\dots f(x_n)$` where $f$ is some non-zero linear functional on $X$.  Then take `$x_2^*=\dots=x_n^*=y$, where $y$ is chosen so that $f(y)=1$.

Comment: My previous comment was originally intended to be a comment on Kate's answer, but MO tells me I can't comment there.

Comment: @Andreas: I just realized that there is a problem with the first suggestion and I have deleted the answer, please put your comment as an answer, it seems that it is what Dan is looking for.

Comment: Thanks Professor Blass, that seems to work! And many congrats to Tim on his recent offer!   Tim and I share an advisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Kate's suggestion, I'm posting my previous comment as an answer.  Choose any non-zero linear functional $f$ on $X$ and any vector $y\in X$ such that $f(y)=1$.  Define  $\mathcal L(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$
 to be the product $L(x_1)f(x_2)\dots f(x_n)$ and take all of 
$x_2^*,\dots x_n^*$ to be $y$.